# What version of Casino (1995) is the uncut version?

Tags: alternate-version, casino

I cannot for the life of me find the proper uncut version of Martin Scorsese's Casino. Do you know where I can find it?

The version is instantly recognizable as it has a gory close up of the pen during the neck stabbing scene and in the "vice torture" scene you see the eye getting popped out of the skull, instead of the cutaway. There are a number of other small additions.

I used to have this version back in the VHS days but years after dumping VHS I still can not find the real uncut version of Casino...

... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've voted to close. There's plenty of [internet 'chatter'](https://www.reddit.com/r/lostmedia/comments/101pb8i/fully_lost_possible_extended_and_more_brutal/) about an alleged uncut version, but nobody seems to have any evidence it exists, which puts this question firmly into the 'Mandela effect' category.